# Different decimal expansions for the same real number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am working through [Foundations of Mathematics (2015)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/019870643X) by Ian Stewart and David Tall. On page 39, the authors provide the following proof which I am struggling to understand. Note that decimal points are indicated by ${\bullet}$ to distinguish them from $...$

> If a number $x$ has two different decimal expansions, then, without loss in generality, we can take
>
> $x = a_0 \bullet a_1...a_{n-1}a_n... = a_0 \bullet a_1...a_{n-1}b_n... \qquad$ (i)
>
> where $a_n < b_n$
>
> Multiply through by $10^n$ to get:
>
> $a_0a_1... a_{n-1}a_n\bullet a_{n+1}... = a_0a_1 ... a_{n-1}b_n \bullet \, a_{n+1}... \qquad$ (ii)
>
> where $a_n < b_n$
>
> Subtracting the whole number $a_0a_1...a_{n-1}a_n$ gives:
>
> $0 \, \bullet a_{n+1}... = k \, \bullet b_{n+1} ... \qquad$ (iii)
>
> where $ k = b_{n+1} - a_{n+1} > 0$ is a positive integer.
>
> But the first decimal is $0 \, \bullet a_{n+1}... < 0.999... \le 1$ and the second exceeds by the positive integer $k$. So they can be equal only if $k=1$ and both decimals represent the same limiting value 1.

My question pertains to equation (iii). I understand the LHS, i.e. why we get $0 \, \bullet a_{n+1}...$

It seems to me that the authors assume that the two representations of $x$ only vary in one position, i.e. $b_n$. Hence, for the RHS, my understanding is that the new number should be $k \, \bullet a_{n+1}...$, where $k = b_n - a_n > 0$.

After all, in equation (ii), the integer after the decimal point is $a_{n+1}$. Why does this "morph" into $b_{n+1}$ in equation (iii), given that we subtract the whole number $a_0a_1...a_{n-1}a_n$? Shouldn't the integers after the decimal point remain the same? Similarly, why is $k = b_{n+1} - a_{n+1}$?

Comment: I think it is just a typo. The digit following $b_n$ in (ii) should be $b_{n+1}$ just as in (iii). Basically, if they differ, then there is a first digit where they differ, which is the nth digit for some n. Everything after that first difference has no effect on the argument that follows. Similarly, the indices in their description of k are also wrong. It's just bad error proofing.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis is right. He's pointed out the two typos.  You should consider writing the publisher and ccing the authors.+1 for close reading - you were right to be puzzled.

Comment: @EthanBolker: I will write the publisher. I checked the publisher's and authors' websites and no errata have been posted so far.