# Finding the limit of a sequence (different decimal expansions for the same real number)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am working through [Foundations of Mathematics (2015)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/019870643X) by Ian Stewart and David Tall. On page 39, the authors provide the following example. This is a distinct question from my [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263981/different-decimal-expansions-for-the-same-real-number) regarding the same page. Note that decimal points are indicated by $\bullet$ to distinguish them from ...

> **Example 2.13:** Suppose $a_1 = 1$ and in general $a_{n+1} = a_n + (\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$, then trivially $(a_n)$ is increasing and a calculation gives $a_n = 2 - (\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$, so the sequence is bounded above by 2. Using the same method to calculate the decimal expansion using definition (2.2)... the limit of the sequence $(a_n)$ is then found to be:
>
> $b_0 \bullet b_1b_2...b_n... = 1 \bullet 99...9...$

Where definition 2.2 is a way to find the decimal expansion of a real number:

> $a_0 \bullet a_1a_2...a_n < x \le a_0 \bullet a_1a_2...a_n + (\frac{1}{10})^n$

My understanding is that if $a_{n+1} = a_n + (\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$, then $a_n = a_{n+1} - (\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$. In the first blockquote, when the authors say "a calculation gives $a_n = 2 - (\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$", do we assume this as a given? Otherwise, surely $a_{n+1}$ cannot equal $2$ for all cases?

A separate question is why, in blockquote 2, the limit is denoted using $b_n$ notation when the original sequence is denoted by $a_n$ notation. Is this standard?

The authors provide the following example after the one above. I am including it in case it is relevant to **Example 2.13**:

> To cover all cases, we introduce the following:
>
> **Definition 2.14:** The value of an infinite decimal $a_0 \bullet a_1a_2...a_n...$ is the limit $l$ of the sequence $(d_n)$ of decimals to $n$ decimal places, where $d_n = a_0 \bullet a_1a_2...a_n$.

Comment: is the equation in the first line meant to be $a_{n+1} = a_n + (\frac{1}{2})^n$?

Comment: @videlity: No, I checked the book and the equation is $a_{n+1} = a_n + (\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$. I have found typos in the book before, so if the example makes sense with $a_{n+1} = a_n + (\frac{1}{2})^n$, then I'd appreciate it if you could explain.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense with that.
Since using that formula, $a_2 = a_1+1 = 2$ and $a_3 = a_2 + \frac{1}{2} = 2.5$ and $a_4 = 2.75$. So either the first equation should be what I wrote above, or $a_n = 3-(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation isn't too difficult which is why they probably left it out.
Note that 
$$a_1=1, \\a_2 = a_1+\frac{1}{2} = 1+\frac{1}{2}, \\a_3 = a_2 + \frac{1}{2^2} = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}$$ 
and in general,
$$a_n = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}. $$
This is an geometric progression with common factor $r=\frac{1}{2}$ and using the formula, we get,
$$a_n = \frac{1-\frac{1}{2^n}}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = 2-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}.$$

This answers your first question. I'm not sure about the other question. I think why they used $b_i$ is just because they used $a_i$ earlier and they stand for different things. $b_i$ stands for the $i$th digit in the decimal, while $a_i$ is a term in the sequence.